# attempt to insert nil object from objects[0] in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a dynamic top menu.
I have to get some data from a json request and display this data in one of the sections of the top menu. I'm new in Objective-C. I also tried with NSMutableArrays and I had an error. Only one MutableArray and I can show the top menu. I am following this third party framework for top menu “https://github.com/dopcn/DOPNavbarMenu”.

```
- (DOPNavbarMenu *)menu {
    if (_menu == nil) {
        [strArray objectAtIndex:0];

        NSLog(@"Random Selection is:%@",strArray);

        _menu = [[DOPNavbarMenu alloc] initWithItems:@[strArray]  width:self.view.dop_width maximumNumberInRow:_numberOfItemsInRow];
        _menu.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _menu.separatarColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _menu.delegate = self;
    }

    return _menu;
}

-(void)loadData
{
    strResponse=[dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];

    strMsg=[strResponse valueForKey:@"Text"];

    NSLog(@“string message  is :%@",strMsg);
    NSLog(@"String Response is :%@",strResponse);
    NSLog(@"Text Response is: %@",strMsg);

    strArray =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [strArray addObject:strMsg];

    NSLog(@"Array values are - %@", strArray);
}
```

Array values are: Life Style,Care Plans,Trackers/Diaries,Questionnaires/Assessments.

but i got exception like this:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

Comment: Please put your code into code tags (4 spaces indention)

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Thanks for your response. but i cant get you..

Comment: user3201089 or Surya, please read the SO documentation. Code citation should be formatted as code.

Comment: Are you sure that `menu` method is called after `loadData` finishes?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad no sorry

Comment: @Losiowaty thanks for your response.. but i want to call menu method before loadData finishes

Comment: You want to display an empty menu?  And you are wondering why it crashes?

Comment: @Avi please guide me.. how to add array value to menu????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, per your comment

> but i want to call menu method before loadData finishes

the issue lies here :

```
_menu = [[DOPNavbarMenu alloc] initWithItems:@[strArray] width:self.view.dop_width maximumNumberInRow:_numberOfItemsInRow];
```

Before `loadData` is run, I assume that `strArray` is `nil`. This causes this part `@[strArray]` to fail - this creates a new array with `strArray` as its only element, which cannot be `nil`.

I also assume that you wanted to rather pass `strArray` itself there, not wrap it in another array.

Now, if you call `menu` before populating `strArray` in `loadData`, there will likely be no items present in the menu, unless you have a way to update it with new items after `loadData` finishes.

To summarise : to fix your immediate issue, you should change the above line to this :

```
_menu = [[DOPNavbarMenu alloc] initWithItems:strArray width:self.view.dop_width maximumNumberInRow:_numberOfItemsInRow];
```

which should work, but there won't be any items present in the menu, because of reasons explained above.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. but i got nil value.Random Selection is:(null)

Comment: Yes, like I said - in your code, you create `strArray` in `loadData`. If `menu` method is called before `loadData`, then `strArray` is bound to be `nil`. Ideally, you'd create your menu, load the data from web and then refresh the menu.

Comment: my issue fix. but no items present in the menu

Comment: @VijaySanghavi - there is a link to the github page with it in the question, no need to clutter it.

Comment: @user3201089 - again, that is because `strArray` is created and populated after creating the menu.

Comment: @Losiowaty will you update my code. i cant findout where is the issue. plz i am new to objective-c

Comment: Let us [continue in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97526/continuation-from-comments)